# pycharm console errror, console not starting properly

Tags: python, pycharm

i got this error by doing nothing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 8, in <module>
    from code import InteractiveConsole
ImportError: cannot import name 'InteractiveConsole' from 'code' (C:\Users\jainil\PycharmProjects\untitled\code.py)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pydevconsole import InterpreterInterface, process_exec_queue, start_console_server, init_mpl_in_console
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevconsole_code_for_ironpython import InteractiveConsole
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevconsole_code_for_ironpython.py", line 105
    except SyntaxError, err:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

closed pycharm
```

this was anoying problem. can anyone help?
can anyone tell what i did?

Comment: problem is solved, by removing one file from my project. why can't i name my python file code.py ? it contains code, and i decided to name it code.py , but pycharm crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have accidentally created code.py in my working directory. just naming problem. so my advice is that don't create code.py in pycharm project. it will destroy your pycharm. i just deleted that python file from my project and all is good now. so thanks for help. interactive console was damaged by just one file, code.py